# Android- Public FTP sites to test uploading

Tags: testing, upload, ftp, sites

Is there any public FTP site to test uploading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some free web space hosting sites (e.g. http://www.awardspace.com/) offer FTP access for site management, which could be used to test uploading... not sure what's the relation to Android though.